# Remove white space from scraped text

Tags: php, web, web-scraping, fopen

```
$url = 'MyUrl';

$contents = file_get_contents($url); 

function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); 
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);
    return $data;
}

$svetaines_turinys = trim(scrape_between($contents, "<table border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\">", "</table>"));

$fp = fopen("autogidas.php", "w+"); 

fwrite ($fp, "$svetaines_turinys"); 

fclose ($fp); 

$fh = fopen("autogidas.php", 'r') or die("negalima atidaryti");

while(! feof($fh)) {

    $visa_data1 = fgets($fh);

    $visa_data = trim($visa_data1);

    $pavadinimas = trim(scrape_between($visa_data, "<span class=\"ttitle2\">", "</span>"));
    $metai = trim(scrape_between($visa_data, "<span class=\"ttitle1\">", "</span>"));
    $kaina = trim(scrape_between($visa_data, "<span class=\"ttitle1\" style='float: left;'>", "<br /><span class=\"grey\">"));

    echo "$pavadinimas<br> $metai <br> $kaina . <br><br>";
}

fclose($fh);
```

Output is working fine, but the problem is the output with a lot of free space, I tried to use `trim()`, but it didn't solved the problem.

Comment: exactly what does this `scrape_between` function do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use regex to accomplish this task, something like this will work perfectly:

```
$metai = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ',scrape_between($visa_data, "<span class=\"ttitle1\">", "</span>"));
```

Just do it on every var with the same problem.

Comment: So it's not whitespace, it's more like "new line", try with this :

preg_replace("/(\r?\n){2,}/", "\n\n", $yourVariable);

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to remove multiple space and just leave a single space you could use `str_replace()` like this

```
function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
    $data = stristr($data, $start); 
    $data = substr($data, strlen($start));
    $stop = stripos($data, $end);
    $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);
    return str_replace('  ', ' ', $data);
}
```

Comment: Can you show us exactly what this white space is made up of, maybe its not just spaces

Comment: You are going to have to write something a lot more complex to extract useful data from that scrape. Look at the page-source of that page to see what you are dealing with